React native error while passing data from screen to another
i have a problem i have created an interface that pass array named squares from this interface i to interfafce i+1 . i have created an interface i+2 when i want to return from i+2 to i+1 i get  a problem said "cannot read property 'squares' of undefined" how to solve this problem
interface i :
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <ButtonBlanc
          title="Précedent"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ChoqArecap")}
        />
        <ButtonRouge
          title="Suivant"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ChoqBrecap", { squares 
              })}
        />
      </View>

interface i+1 :
     let { squares } = useRoute().params;
       if (typeof squares === "undefined") {
            squares = Array(12).fill(false);
      }

interface i+2 :
Some other code not depending from the array squares which mean that i didn't pass it from i+1 to i+2
i tried to solve the problem like that but still the same problem
    let { squares } = useRoute().params;
      if (typeof squares === "undefined") {
           squares = Array(12).fill(false);
     }

